# Add HTML stuff to page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a Google Chrome extension that automatically adds a Bold button to the page.

Here's a before:

[image: Before]

Here's the after:

[image: After]

I manually added the button by hand using the Inspect Element option in Google Chrome using this code and placing it in the appropriate location:

```
<input type="button" name="bold" value="Bold">
```

The part where I'm running into trouble is figuring out how choose where I want to add an HTML snippet where ever I want in an existing webpage and inserting the HTML snippet with JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: tell me your requirement in one or two sentences.

Comment: You have to look into [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range).

Comment: Athul AK, basically I just want to programmically (JavaScript) add `<input type="button" name="bold" value="Bold">` into a specific location in the webpage's HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question as it stands is a bit broad, but I believe I understand what you are asking.

First you need to find out where you're getting the text from. You'll have to use your browser's developer tools (Inspect Element, as you said above) and find the ID or class of the toolbar.

For example, the ID of the edit toolbar above the answer I'm writing right now is `wmd-button-row`:

[image: Developer tools]

Then you'll have to append the button. There are two ways to do this: you can create the node using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and add its properties or you can just add onto the element's `innerHTML`, which is probably simpler in this case, since you already have the HTML for the button.

So, you'd do this:

```
document.getElementById("TOOLBAR-ID").innerHTML += "<input type='button' name='bold' value='Bold'>";
```

Not that I've changed your double parentheses (`"`) to single parentheses (`'`) to stop them from breaking the string. Alternatively, you could escape them with a backslash (`\`).

The other way to do it would be to use [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) as follows:

```
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.setAttribute("type", "button");
button.setAttribute("name", "bold");
button.setAttribute("value", "Bold");
document.getElementById("TOOLBAR-ID").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding quick enough, I can see where you're going.  But how would you get the children of the element by class?  Let's say I use `document.getElementByClass("BoxContent")`  How would I access the td at the bottom highlighted in blue?  I want to place a button there, just for example.  http://i.imgur.com/Ky5ho4t.png

Comment: @Evan Good question. It should be `document.getElementsByClass()` (element-**s** because multiple elements can have the same class, whereas only one element can/should have a unique ID). Since that returns a NodeList, you can get specific elements in the same way you'd access elements of an array (bracket syntax). So, if it's the first element with the `BoxContent` class on the page, it'd be `document.getElementsByClassName("BoxContent")[0]`. Then to get the children, you can use `.children` and array syntax again.

Comment: @Evan So, try `document.getElementsByClassName("BoxContent")[0].children[10].children[1].innerHTML += "<input type='button' name='bold' value='Bold'>";` (this assumes that this is the first element on the page with the `BoxContent` class).